# Android unmute doesn't switch to mute

Tags: android, checkbox, audio, android-audiomanager, mute

I have this checkbox which is supposed to mute all the sounds when it is checked. When I run the app and the checkbox is unchecked the sound is on. Then I check the box and the sounds are muted! When I uncheck the checkbox the sounds remain muted. What am I doing wrong??

Here is the code I use

```
public class Settings extends Activity {

CheckBox chb;
boolean m;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    final SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("mute", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    m = prefs.getBoolean("mute", false);

    chb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

    chb.setChecked(m);

    final AudioManager amanager=(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, m);

    chb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
            if ( buttonView.isChecked() == true )
            {
                m = true;
                amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("mute", true);
                editor.commit();
            }
            if (buttonView.isChecked() == false)
            {
                m = false;
                System.out.println("unmute");
                amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("mute", false);
                editor.commit();
            }

        }
    });

}
```

I update in case someone finds it usefull.

The mute requests for a given stream are cumulative: the AudioManager can receive several mute requests from one or more clients and the stream will be unmuted only when the same number of unmute requests are received.

For a better user experience, applications MUST unmute a muted stream in onPause() and mute is again in onResume() if appropriate.

In my case the problem was that when I check the checkbox I mute the sounds. When I go back to the settings activity this code is executed again

```
final SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("mute", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
m = prefs.getBoolean("mute", false);

chb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

chb.setChecked(m);

final AudioManager amanager=(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, m);
```

and mutes the sounds again! So we have 2 mutes (cumulative) and we need to unmute it twice.

Comment: why don't you use the 'isChecked' parameter in the onCheckedChanged method?

Comment: and I guess the ```m = true;``` and ```m = false;``` in the ```onCheckedChanged``` is redundant when your onCreate is not bigger and you don't need the variable anymore. correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: I had used isChecked but and the problem was still remaining and then I used `buttonView.isChecked()` @Simon

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the listener is called before the view is updated, so you need to use the isChecked passed to you 
Switch your onchecked listener to this:

```
 public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
            if (isChecked == true )
            {
                m = true;
                amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("mute", true);
                editor.commit();
            }
            else
            {
                m = false;
                System.out.println("unmute");
                amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("mute", false);
                editor.commit();
            }

        }
```

Comment: This is how I wrote the code before the one I posted!I tried it again but still the same..

Comment: Just tested the code and it worked, maybe you are muting somewhere else?

Comment: I tested it on android 2.3.3...i'll try another api!

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4235 i found this so i hope 2.3 is the problem

Comment: I don't think that's the problem :( try putting Log.d messages and comment out the mute/unmute logic, just to determine where the problem is